# Python regular expression retrieving numbers between two different delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
"h=56,7,1,d=88,9,1,h=58,8,1,d=45,h=100,d=,"
```

I would like to use regular expressions to extract the groups:

- group1 56,7,1
- group2 88,9,1
- group3 58,8,1
- group4 45
- group5 100
- group6 null

My ultimate goal is to have tuples such as (group1, group2), (group3, group4), (group5, group6). I am not sure if this all can be accomplished with regular expressions.

I have the following regular expression with gives me partial results

```
(?<=h=|d=)(.*?)(?=h=|d=)
```

The matches have an extra comma at the end like `56,7,1,` which I would like to remove and `d=,` is not returning a null.

Comment: Why do you insist that these be extracted with regular expressions?  What if you were to split on = and then take the RHS of each of those and split them on commas.  Iterate over enumerate() to skip the first one and work with [:-1] of each to discard the (apparently unwanted) 'd' and 'h' labels.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because they have 11 reputation which suggests unfamiliarity with python and they needs to use it just for this specific task.

Answer (score 4):

You likely do not need to use regex.  A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can likely do what you need like:

#### Code:

```
def split_it(a_string):
    if not a_string.endswith(','):
        a_string += ','
    return [x.split(',')[:-1] for x in a_string.split('=') if len(x)][1:]
```

#### Test Code:

```
tests = (
    "h=56,7,1,d=88,9,1,h=58,8,1,d=45,h=100,d=,",
    "h=56,7,1,d=88,9,1,d=,h=58,8,1,d=45,h=100",
)

for test in tests:
    print(split_it(test))
```

#### Results:

```
[['56', '7', '1'], ['88', '9', '1'], ['58', '8', '1'], ['45'], ['100'], ['']]
[['56', '7', '1'], ['88', '9', '1'], [''], ['58', '8', '1'], ['45'], ['100']]
```

Comment: +1 for not using regex, however maybe the letter without a number is not the last entry (i.e. `h=56,7,1,d=88,9,1,d=,h=58,8,1,d=45,h=100`)

Comment: Probably violates the basic structure, but sure why not?

Answer (score 1):

You could *match* rather than *split* using the expression

```
[dh]=([\d,]*),
```

and grab the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/tSpUaG/1).

---

That is

```
[dh]=     # d or h, followed by =
([\d,]*)  # capture d and s 0+ times
,         # require a comma afterwards
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'[dh]=([\d,]*),')

string = "h=56,7,1,d=88,9,1,h=58,8,1,d=45,h=100,d=,"

numbers = [m.group(1) for m in rx.finditer(string)]
print(numbers)
```

Which yields

```
['56,7,1', '88,9,1', '58,8,1', '45', '100', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `([a-z]=)([0-9,]+)(,)?`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/x8W4Sz/1/)

just you need add index to group

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$` in positive lookahead to match against the end of the string:

```
import re

input_str = "h=56,7,1,d=88,9,1,h=58,8,1,d=45,h=100,d=,"
groups = []
for x in re.findall('(?<=h=|d=)(.*?)(?=d=|h=|$)', input_str):
    m = x.strip(',')
    if m:
        groups.append(m.split(','))
    else:
        groups.append(None)

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
[['56', '7', '1'], ['88', '9', '1'], ['58', '8', '1'], ['45'], ['100'], None]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have assumed that parameters will only have numerical values. If it is so, then you can try this.
(?<=h=|d=)([0-9,]*)

Hope it helps.